# Запрос данных из БД

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, для построения графика. Как сделать запрос данных из базы mysql , чтобы в `series: name` и `y` запрашивались из БД. Желательно развернутый ответ, потому что я с `javascript` на Вы.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#my_chart ').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Популярность браузеров в сентябре 2015'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    showInLegend: false
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: "Доля браузера",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer",
                    y: 7.2
                }, {
                    name: "Chrome",
                    y: 65.9,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                }, {
                    name: "Firefox",
                    y: 20.6
                }, {
                    name: "Safari",
                    y: 3.6
                }, {
                    name: "Opera",
                    y: 1.4
                }, {
                    name: "Другие",
                    y: 1.3
                }]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: Из **какой** БД?

Comment: База данных mysql

Comment: Но mysql у вас на сервере. А javascript работает в браузере у клиента и к базе доступ может получить только послав обычный http запрос на ваш сервер. Так что данные из базы должен получать некий код на сервере (php, node.js, и прочие), и отдавать его в каком то виде (html, готовый график, json) клиенту

Comment: Возможно сделать запрос в php и потом добавить переменные(массив) в java, только не получается вот сделать это

Comment: @Dima [Посмотрите тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598659/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-run-mysql-queries)

Comment: все просто http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/07/highcharthighstock.html